# RichFaces commandbutton onclick methods

Tags: javascript, jsf, richfaces, ajax4jsf

I'm using a RichFaces commandbutton and I need it to execute two functions on click, one after the other. Right now, I have the code like so:

```
<a4j:commandButton  styleClass="btn-hide"
                                        onl
                                        id="btnId"  
                                        type="submit" 
                                        value="addNew"
                                        rendered="true" 
                                        reRender="panel"
                                        eventsQueue="eventQueue"    
                                        status="eventQueue" 
                                        actionListener="#{(someMethod.something)}"                                           
                                        oncomplete="javascript:something;this.disabled=false"
                                        onclick="Bean.setDesc(document.getElementById('inputArea').value);this.disable=false"
                                        ignoreDupResponses="true"
                                        immediate= "true"> 
                                          <s:conversationId></s:conversationId>
                            </a4j:commandButton>
```

If you look at the onclick portion, I need the Bean.setDesc to run first and then this.disabled=false. How would I go about doing this chronologically?

Thanks

Comment: onclick is a client side method. is Bean a javascript object or are you looking for a way to trigger an ajax request?

Comment: Bean is not a javascript object. It's a java method.

Comment: and is inputArea a jsf component?

Comment: Yes, inputArea is a jsf component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a code stub to get you started. You'll want to use a4j:jsFunction if you are looking to grab values directly from the client and pass them to a server method with javascript.

```
<h:form id="form1" prependId="false">        

    <a4j:jsFunction 
        name="setDesc"
        action="#{exampleBean.actionMethod()}" 
        immediate="true">
        <a4j:param name="inputAreaValue" assignTo="#{exampleBean.desc}"/>
    </a4j:jsFunction>

    <h:commandButton id="button" onclick="setDesc(document.getElementById('inputArea').value); this.disabled = true;" />
</h:form>
```

and the managed bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "exampleBean")
@SessionScoped
public class ExampleBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6823632613070575039L;

    private String desc;

    public String getDesc() { return desc; }
    public void setDesc(String desc) { this.desc = desc; }

    /**
     * Action Method 
     */
    public void actionMethod() {
        // do something here
    }


}
```

Comment: Thanks, but could you please explain what the action="#{jsFunctionBean.actionMethod}" is?

Comment: that can be any action method you want to invoke. In your example you had actionListener="#{(someMethod.something)}". Presumably you want to set the value of inputArea on Bean.desc and then do something else server side? If you don't want that functionality you can just remove the attribute.